# Can i perform Marshalling outside of my main method, JAVAXB, JAVAFX

Tags: java, xml, javafx, jaxb

I am having trouble understanding how to use JAXB to save info on an XML file. I am building a GUI in which saves information from the user to an XML file. I want to have the ListManagement class handle this by having another class call the marshal() method, in which it should add the object to the XML file. but it does not.

I get a 1 counts of IllegalAnnotation Exceptions

**ListManagement class**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class ListManagement 

{

    File file = new File("src\\view\\DataFile.xml");    

    public ListManagement()
    {

    }

    public void marshal(Song track)
    {
        try
        {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Song.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(track, file);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

**Song Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@XmlRootElement

public class Song 
{   
    private String name;

    public Song(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you stop hiding the error message, you'll see what is wrong.

Change your `catch` statement to:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Then you'll get the real error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Song does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at Song

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at ListManagement.marshal(Test.java:18)
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

That should be specific enough for you to figure out.

When getting errors, *always* look at the **full stacktrace**.